# What could be the initialization and control statements?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

This problem needs to be solved using Nested for loop only and only in C.
Hope, you all will help me.

```
Sample input            Sample output
3                       1___1
                        12_21
                        12321

4                       1_____1
                        12___21
                        123_321
                        1234321
```

I have tried to write here some of my code. But it fails at the underscore thing.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
     int i,n,j,m;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int k=n;
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
           printf("%d",j);
        }
        for(m=k;m>=0;m--)
        {
           printf("_");
        }
        printf("\n");
        k=k-2;;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Google for palindrome. There should be tons of samples out there.

Comment: Yes, I know the palindrome. But, can't settle the underscore thing.

Comment: You may do it with `char`s. There is a `'_'` you can use for output of `_`. The rest is fiddling with counters. You should expose at least your code you have so far to expect more help. (You can [edit] your question.)

Comment: edit done. it took some time though

Comment: Avoid naming variables `i` and `j` (and `l`) that appear next to each other, same vor `m` and `n`. Just asking for trouble by confusing them. In fact, avoid one-letter-identifiers (except for loop conters and things like that), find appropriate descriptive names instead.

Comment: Note: beause all indexes in C start from 0, all `for` loops traditionally start at 0 too, so `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` etc.

Comment: What you urgently miss is the "art" of debugging. (Sorry, actually it is a basic skill for developers.) Please, learn to use the debugger. Visual Studio has a very nice built-in and I once found a complete introduction in MSDN (found with google). On Linux, there is at least `gdb` which is very powerful but a little bit more difficult to use. (There are GUI front-ends for gdb as well but I don't have any experience with them.) The debugger allows you to execute your program line by line and watch the variables for each step. That helps you to uncover your issues by yourself (I'm sure).

Comment: Thanks for the advices guys. I will surely try them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int limit;  
    for (; printf("limit: "), scanf(" %d", &limit) != 1;) {
        fputs("Input error :(", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int line = 1; line <= limit; ++line, putchar('\n')) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= line; ++i)
            printf("%d", i);
        for (int i = line + 1; i < 2 * limit - line; ++i)
            putchar('_');
        for (int i = (line == limit) ? line - 1 : line; i; --i)
            printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it still looks so complex for the begineers like me. Though, I can get the logic

Comment: If the input loop exits on first failure, why is it a loop at all?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *using Nested for loop only* ^^